# кнопка для слайдера

Tags: javascript

не понимаю что я делаю не так — почему не работает кнопка? причем если через SetInterval делаю всё работает ссылка на jsfiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/dglushkov/g7y5p4aj/17/

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide '),
  nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

function Slider(images) {
  this.images = images;
  let i = 0;

  this.next = function() {        
 this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
 i++;
 if(i >= this.images.length) {
   i = 0;
 }
 this.images[i].classList.add('showed');        
  }
}
   
let slider = new Slider(images);

nextBtn.onclick = () => {
  slider.next();
}

/*  setInterval(function(){
   slider.next();
  }, 1000);*/
```

```css
slider {
 width: 768px;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.slide {
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}

.showed {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="next">next</a>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slide showed"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь для ссылки `<a class="next">Next</a>` нужно задать `preventDefault`, потому как по умолчанию клик по ссылке обновляет страницу

Answer (score 0):

Хз, всё работает. Я твой же код вставил в местный редактор и завёл. Кнопка `next` внизу.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide '),
     nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

  function Slider(images) {
   this.images = images;
   let i = 0;

   this.next = function() {
    
    this.images[i].classList.remove('showed');
    i++;
    
    if(i >= this.images.length) {
     i = 0;
    }

    this.images[i].classList.add('showed');
    
   }

  }
   
  let slider = new Slider(images);

  nextBtn.onclick = () => {
   slider.next();
  }

//  setInterval(function(){
//   slider.next();
//  }, 1000);
```

```css
.wr {
  position: relative;
}
slider {
 width: 768px;
 position: relative;
}

.slide {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.slide {
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}

.showed {
 opacity: 1;
}

.next {
position: relative;
top: 410px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>

 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slide showed"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/590x400" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt=""></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: да здесь работает. странно но в хроме у меня на миллисекунду меняет изображение и назад к первому возвращает

Comment: а здесь https://jsfiddle.net/dglushkov/g7y5p4aj/17/ как у тебя работает?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
let slider = new Slider(images);

        nextBtn.onclick = function(){
            slider.next();
            return false;
        }
```